# Maven release:perform problem

Tags: maven-2, maven, release-management, maven-release-plugin

I have a problem when i'm trying to run the Maven task: `mvn -X release:perform`

```
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO] [INFO]    task-segment: [deploy]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:12 for project: null:maven-resources-plugin:maven-plugin:2.3 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:9 for project: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:12 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache:apache:pom:4 for project: org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:9 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:8 for project: null:maven-compiler-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0.2 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:5 for project: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:8 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache:apache:pom:3 for project: org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:5 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire:pom:2.4.3 for project: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:maven-plugin:null from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:7 for project: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire:pom:2.4.3 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Adding managed dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin
[INFO] [DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.4.3
[INFO] [DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.4.3
[INFO] [DEBUG]   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:10 for project: null:maven-jar-plugin:maven-plugin:2.2 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:13 for project: null:maven-install-plugin:maven-plugin:2.3 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:11 for project: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:13 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache:apache:pom:5 for project: org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:11 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:11 for project: null:maven-deploy-plugin:maven-plugin:2.4 from the repository.
[INFO] [DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:8 for project: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:11 from the repository.
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Cannot execute mojo: resources. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: i have also release:perform fail error.Please go to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721155/maven-releaseperform-failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you executed mvn release:prepare before ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message

Cannot execute mojo: resources. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, 
   but the build is not using one

it looks like you don't have a pom.xml in the folder you are trying to start mvn release:prepare in....BTw. Have you executed mvn release:prepare before ?

Comment: Thanks for the response khmarbaise! I have a pom.xml in the project folder where i'm executing mvn release:prepare. Is the first time that i'm executing mvn release:prepare.

Comment: Have you correctly defined the scm area? developerConnection and connection pointing to trunk/master?