# Maven release:perform failure

Tags: svn, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am getting error when I am applying `release:perform`. It is unable to uploading the artifacts into nexus repository .

In my SVN 3 directory :-

Branch , trunk and tag.

When I am applying `release:prepare`  it executes successfully and create a tag with removing the snapshot from pom.xml. And change the trunk/pom.xml to next version with snapshot.

Before prepare  Trunk/pom.xml  version 2.0-SNAPSHOT
After prepare Trunk/pom.xml version 2.1-SNAPSHOT
After prepare tags/pom.xml version 2.0

But, when I am executing release:perform it shows error. 
What I did wrong. I am putting my pom.xml and settings.xml (in my local) files.

### pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.yyy.aaa.curo.fabric.rabbitmq.experiments</groupId>
  <artifactId>curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments</artifactId>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <version>2.0.45</version>

<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
     <id>curorelease</id>
     <name>Curo Releases</name>
     <url>http://nexusrepo.yyy.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
     <id>curosnapshot</id>
     <name>Curo Snapshots</name>
     <url>http://nexusrepo.yyy.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-snapshots/</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>


  <name>Curo Fabric Component for RabbitMQ</name>
  <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <camel.version>2.10.4</camel.version>
  </properties>


<scm>
   <connection>scm:svn:http://aaasvn.yyy.yyy.com:1080/SVNROOT/CURO/Experiments/migration/tags/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.45</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://aaasvn.yyy.yyy.com:1080/SVNROOT/CURO/Experiments/migration/tags/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.45</developerConnection>
   <url>scm:svn:http://aaasvn.yyy.yyy.com:1080/SVNROOT/CURO/Experiments/migration/tags/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.45</url>
</scm>



 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>thirdparty</id>
      <name>Repository for Third Party</name>
      <url>http://nexusrepo.yyy.yyy.com/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>curosnapshot</id>
      <name>Repository for Curo Snapshots</name>
      <url>http://nexusrepo.yyyy.yyyyy.com/content/repositories/curo-snapshots/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>curorelease</id>
      <name>Repository for Curo Releases</name>
      <url>http://nexusrepo.yyyy.yyyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>snapshot.fusesource.org</id>
      <name>FuseSource Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>  
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <configuration>
       <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
        <id>default</id>
        <goals>
                        <goal>perform</goal>
                </goals> 
        <configuration>
            <tagBase>http://aaasvn.rrr.rrrr.com:1080/SVNROOT/CURO/Experiments/migration/tags/</tagBase>
                <pomFileName>/Users/manojkumarbardhan/QURO_PROJECT/rabbit_trunk/pom.xml</pomFileName>   
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>


      <!-- to generate the MANIFEST-FILE of the bundle -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Private-Package>com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.*</Private-Package>
            <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

       <!-- to run the example using mvn camel:run -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

### settings.xml in local

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>merlinsnap</id>
      <username>merlinsuite-snapshots</username>
      <password>xxxx123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>merlinrel</id>
      <username>merlinsuite-release</username>
      <password>sxxx123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
     <id>thirdparty</id>
     <username>thirdparty</username>
     <password>xxxxinternal1</password>
   </server>
<server>
     <id>snapshots</id>
     <username>admin</username>
     <password>admin123</password>
</server>
   <server>
       <id>curorelease</id>
       <username>curodeploy</username>
       <password>cur0d3pl0y</password>
    <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
    <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
    <configuration>
                        <sshExecutable>plink</sshExecutable>
                        <scpExecutable>pscp</scpExecutable>
                </configuration>
   </server>
   <server>
       <id>curosnapshot</id>
       <username>curodeploy</username>
       <password>cur0d3pl0y</password>
    <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
    <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
    <configuration>
                        <sshExecutable>plink</sshExecutable>
                        <scpExecutable>pscp</scpExecutable>
                </configuration>
   </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>Repository Proxy</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>ist.nexus.maven.central</id>
          <name>Maven Central</name>
          <url>http://aaamaven.yyy.yyy.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/
          </url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>ist.nexus.jboss.public</id>
          <name>JBoss Public</name>
          <url>http://aaamaven.yyy.yyy.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/jboss-public/
          </url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
          <name>JBoss repository</name>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public
          </url>
        </repository>



      </repositories>
    </profile>
<profile>
            <id>sonar-2.0</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
                <sonar.host.url>
                  http://yyyysvn.yyyy.com:9000/
                </sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>Repository</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>curosnapshot</id>
                <name>Curo Fabric Snapshot</name>
                <url>
                http://aaasvn.yyy.yyy.com:1080/SVNROOT/CURO/Experiments/migration/trunk/
                </url>
                <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        <repository>
                        <id>curorelease</id>
                        <name>Curo Fabric Release </name>
                        <url>
                                http://aaasvn.yyy.yyy.com:1080/SVNROOT/CURO/Experiments/migration/tags/
                        </url>
                        <releases>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                                <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                </repository>

    </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Error log (When I am executing `release:perform`) :-

```
[INFO] Uploading: http://nexusrepo.yyy.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/com/yyyy/aaa/curo/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.45/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.45.pom
[INFO] 2/6 KB   
[INFO] 4/6 KB   
[INFO] 6/6 KB   
[INFO]          
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 6.708s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 10 18:53:51 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/81M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact yyy.yyy.yyy.curo.fabric.rabbitmq.experiments:curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments:jar:2.0.45 from/to curorelease (http://nexusrepo.yyy.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/): Access denied to: http://nexusrepo.yyy.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/com/yyy/aaaa/curo/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.45/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.45.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.878s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 10 18:53:51 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.2.1:perform (default-cli) on project curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**EDIT - Run with -X release:perform **

```
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 8.752s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 11 10:09:41 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/81M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.yyy.aaa.curo.fabric.rabbitmq.experiments:curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments:jar:2.0.46 from/to curorelease (http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/): Access denied to: http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/com/yyy/aaa/curo/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.46/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.46.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.yyy.aaa.curo.fabric.rabbitmq.experiments:curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments:jar:2.0.46 from/to curorelease (http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/): Access denied to: http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/com/yyy/aaa/curo/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.46/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.46.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[INFO] Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.yyy.aaa.curo.fabric.rabbitmq.experiments:curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments:jar:2.0.46 from/to curorelease (http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/): Access denied to: http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/com/yyy/aaa/curo/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.46/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.46.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:193)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
[INFO]  ... 19 more
[INFO] Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.yyy.aaa.curo.fabric.rabbitmq.experiments:curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments:jar:2.0.46 from/to curorelease (http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/): Access denied to: http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/com/yyy/aaa/curo/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.46/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.46.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:141)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:157)
[INFO]  ... 21 more
[INFO] Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.yyy.aaa.curo.fabric.rabbitmq.experiments:curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments:jar:2.0.46 from/to curorelease (http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/): Access denied to: http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/com/yyy/aaa/curo/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.46/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.46.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
[INFO]  at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:280)
[INFO]  at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:211)
[INFO]  at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:443)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:137)
[INFO]  ... 23 more
[INFO] Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.yyy.aaa.curo.fabric.rabbitmq.experiments:curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments:jar:2.0.46 from/to curorelease (http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/): Access denied to: http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/aaa/yyy/aaa/curo/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.46/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.46.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
[INFO]  at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
[INFO]  at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
[INFO]  at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:837)
[INFO]  at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.put(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:467)
[INFO]  at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:274)
[INFO]  ... 26 more
[INFO] Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/aaa/yyy/aaa/curo/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.46/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.46.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:554)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:471)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:451)
[INFO]  at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:811)
[INFO]  ... 28 more
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.584s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 11 10:09:41 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.2.1:perform (default-cli) on project curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.2.1:perform (default-cli) on project curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.execute(PerformReleaseMojo.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPerformGoalsPhase.execute(RunPerformGoalsPhase.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:346)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.execute(PerformReleaseMojo.java:132)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:399)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:417)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:81)
    ... 26 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Any comment would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check on the nexus repo server that the "curodeploy" user has the deployment role.

Comment: What part of ***"ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -"*** don't you understand? Did you run it with `-X` to see the full stacktrace?

Comment: Why downvote ? Am I wrong some where ? Yes @JarrodRoberson I will try with -X then update you.

Comment: @splash when I am running 'mvn deploy' at command line (terminal), it works fine and deploy the artifacts into nexus snapshot repo.If user is not proper how it works.And also I have one doubt that in nexus 2 repository is there (snapshot and release). When I am running 'mvn deploy' it only deploy into snapshot . Why ? Why its not doing anything into release ?I need your help.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson , I have posted the stack trace in my question.Please go through it.

Comment: it is pretty clear that the server thinks you don't have permission to deploy to the release repository. `Access denied to: http://nexusrepo.aaa.yyy.com/content/repositories/curo-releases/com/yyy/aaa/curo/fabric/rabbitmq/experiments/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments/2.0.46/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.46.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]`